# Step Back debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

sometimes when I debug in Eclipse, I found some thing wrong so I want come back and debug again, but I want to do that just for couple statements.

I saw

[How to step back in Eclipse debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/step-back-in-eclipse-debugger)

[is it possible to "go back" in java eclipse debugger like dragging the arrow in VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864917/is-it-possible-to-go-back-in-java-eclipse-debugger-like-dragging-the-arrow-in)

and  I know about **Drop to frame** but I can't use this to step back any line I want. I need some thing else. For example if you use debug in Visual Studio, you can drag and drop the debug arrow anywhere you want. You can bring the debugger to previous statement and debug it again. I need something like this in Eclipse but **Drop to frame** doesn't do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The linked answers suggest to use a third-party product to provide exactly this feature. If you don't want to do that and are not satisfied with drop to frame, there is one more option. *You can set a breakpoint before the interesting place (or just drop to that frame), and then evaluate arbitrary code in this context* (see [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cscrapbook.htm) or this [blog post](http://stephanebegaudeau.tumblr.com/post/42852448594/debugging-a-java-application)).